# How to send positional parameters to output

Tags: bash, shell, input, parameters, output

How do I send $1,$2 etc to output in a script. I want to have a script that takes 3 arguments, a sedsrc file, a awksrc file, and a datainput file. I want the sed call to send the output to the awk. I need the awk call to take that input. Then I need the new output to be redirected into a new output file.

Ive tried

```
$1>temp.txt
$2>temp2.txt
```

Comment: ... What do the lines you've written have to do with your problem?

Comment: Just want to know if I am close or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `echo` command:

```
echo "$1" >temp.txt
echo "$2" >temp2.txt
```

If you want the contents of the files named in the positional parameters, use `cat`:

```
cat "$1" >temp.txt
cat "$2" >temp2.txt
```

Comment: When I do this it makes the output the name of the file not whats in the file. If $1 is a .sed file. How do I make that files contents be the output going into temp.txt?

Comment: You use the `cat` command, just like you would if you were doing it by hand in the shell.